# Dynamically import a module Next.js, but with server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import

I have a `[...pageId].tsx` file in the /pages directory.

In `getServerSideProps`, the page will check a CMS, and find a list of components to render. I want to load those components serverside, then render them out, then return the page.

Using next/dynamic like below will load the components, but it will not render them serverside. They will only stream in on the client. In other words: the customer will see 'Loading...' first, then the component renders. That's not what I want, also not for SEO.

```
const getDynamicComponent = (c) => dynamic(() => import(`../../components/${c}`), {
  loading: () => <section>Loading...</section>,
  ssr: true
});

export default function SomePage({page}) {
  // Load dynamic component if necessary
  let DynamicComponent = getDynamicComponent(page.reactComponent);
  }
  return (
     <DynamicComponent page={page} />
  )
}
```

How can I achieve serverside rendering using dynamic imports?

Comment: Hey @willem-mulder did you ever get a solution to this problem? We're running into exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Chenzo no not yet. At the moment, I just import all possible components, store them in a map, and then pick the right one with some custom logic. But that's so wasteful :-(